# Web scraping with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to finish this task on web scraping. On my web page, I take the URL and find what located is between its `<body>` tags. Then, I want to output the content which was found on my web page. I learned that I can use `request` module for this purpose.

The problem is, I cannot show the result in my page's HTML, because I could not save the result of `request`'s work (in POST part)

Here is my code:

```
var request = require("request");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = express.Router();
app.use(session({secret: 'shhhhhhh', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
var sess;

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
    sess = req.session;
    if (app.get('done') === true) {
        console.log(app.get('info'));                    // prints "undefined"
        app.set('done', false);

        res.end(`
            <h1>Show other sites</h1>
            <form action="/" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="site" id="site" placeholder="url"><br>
                <button type="submit">go</button>
                <a href="/">BACK</a>
            </form><br>
            <hr>
            <p>url: ${app.get('site')}</p>
            <hr>
            <div>
            ${app.get('info')}
            </div>
        `);
    }
    else
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    sess = req.session;
    sess.site = req.body.site;
    
    app.set('done', false);
    if (sess.site) {
        app.set('done', true);
        request({
            uri: `${sess.site}`,}, function(error, response, body) {
                app.set('info', body);       // Here I'm trying to save the scraped result
                app.set('site', sess.site);
            }
        );
    }
    res.redirect('/');
})
router.get('/clear', (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/');
    })
})
app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Running at port 3000");
```

Please help me find out what I'm doing wrong and how to save the result of `Request` module for later use.

Comment: Why are you using Express? Why not just a simple command line script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that after following your logic it will be better to think again about it. keep in mind using a global variable is a bad practice!

been said that

you can solve the logic by following these minor changes

install [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

```
npm i node-fetch
```

import it

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

then change the **POST** end point to

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    sess = req.session;
    sess.site = req.body.site;
    app.set('done', false);
    if (sess.site) {
        app.set('done', true);
        await fetch(sess.site)
            .then(resp => resp.text()).then(body => {
                console.log(body)
                app.set('info', body);       //Here I'm trying to save the scrapped result
                app.set('site', sess.site);
            })
    }
    res.redirect('/');

})
```

Comment: That's so cool! Thanks a lot! I just have one more question. The provided solution works like a charm but it shows actual visual content of the provided website. What if I need to show only html content (with tags and stuff) instead?

Comment: change   <div>${app.get('info')}</div>  to  <textarea>${app.get('info')}</textarea>